Google Ads: retrieve Warnings / Alerts / Notifications through API
I have been researching how to retrieve account warnings through the API but have not had much luck yet.
See an example of a warning I am trying to retrieve in the attached file. It reads: ""Your ads aren't running - Make a payment towards your overdue account balance."

I found the following conversation: https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/UdClivchFJY claiming that as of April 4 2022 this feature is not available but has been previously requested.
Does anyone know if there has been any progress on this feature since? Any help is appreciated.

This feature is still not supported: https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/Bw9MPMfL1x4/m/u-A7qf24AQAJ
